# Jquery - Cloning collapsible divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So im trying to build the front end of a form builder however i've run into a problem when trying to clone collapsible elements. Im an absolute beginner at jquery so sorry for the dirty code.
When an element is cloned and it is nested under itself with a modified sortable jquery plugin, any one of the bottom levels collapsible's will open the collapsible of the top level parent (but not any of the other nested elements).

My jquery is:

```
var count = 1;
$("#displayUpload").click(function() {
    var clonecount = 'Uploadpanel' + count;
    var cloneobject = $("#toggleUpload").clone(true).appendTo(".sortable").show();
    $("#Uploadpanel", cloneobject).attr('id', clonecount);
    $(cloneobject, this.id).on("click", (".edit", ".panel-title"), function() {
        $("#" + clonecount, this.id).collapse('toggle');
    });
    $(cloneobject).on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(cloneobject).remove();
    });
    count = count + 1;
});
```

Html:

```
<li id="toggleUpload" data-role="main" class="js-form-element" style="display: none">
    <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-role="collapsible" id="panel3">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title" data-target="#Uploadpanel"
                    href="#Uploadpanel">
                    <a data-target="#Uploadpanel"
                        href="#Uploadpanel" class="edit">
                    File upload
                    </a>
                    <span class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <a data-target="#Uploadpanel"
                        href="#Uploadpanel" class="collapsed">Edit</a>
                    <span class="padding-line">|</span>
                    <a class="remove" href="#">Delete</a>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="Uploadpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                        <p class="font-italic">Label:</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Label">
                    </div>
                    <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                        <p class="font-italic">Placeholder text:</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder message">
                    </div>
                    <div class="margin-bottom-5">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input id="required" type="checkbox"> Required
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="margin-bottom-20">
                        <p class="font-italic">Validation message:</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validation" placeholder="Validation message">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <p class="font-italic">Form input size:</p>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select name="form_select">
                                        <option value="0">100% (1 in a row)</option>
                                        <option value="0">33% (3 in a row)</option>
                                        <option value="0">50% (2 in a row)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <p class="font-italic">Form position:</p>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select name="form_select">
                                        <option value="0">Left</option>
                                        <option value="0">Middle</option>
                                        <option value="0">Right</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Comment: Not entirely clear -- what is the desired behavior, and how is it currently behaving?

Answer (score 0):

There can be some issues using clone on objects that already has event handlers. I had this issue for a while, and I just resolved it by creating a function that generates a new jQuery object, instead of cloning an existing one.